# pymongo gives duplicate key error when i perform multiple insert one after another

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to python and newer to pymongo .

I have multiple insert with pymongo below :

```
jdcredit.insert({"record_id":c,"total_credit":total_credit,"balanced_credit":money_rem})

saved_applied_job.insert({"record_id":c,"seeker_emp_id":emp_ID,"seeker_name":emp_name,"request_id":int(request_id)})
```

I get below duplicate key error on one of them in some circumstance,

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydatalocal.saved_applied_job index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c1b69d9aeae6c54508fe1a1') }
```

mydatalocal is my db name and saved_applied,jdcredit is my collection name.

please help me on this

Comment: Looks like there is an index on column `record_id` which has the same value `c` twice.

Comment: but I am getting error "_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c1b69d9aeae6c54508fe1a1') " not in record_id , is it due to occurance of c twice in record_id ? m stucked here

Comment: So `jdcredit.insert()` succeeds and `saved_applied_job.insert()` fails? It has to do with an index of unique constraint on the `saved_applied_job` collection.

Comment: the value for the c is different for each of above record_id and I even tried having different variable given to record_id instead of c for both but still I am getting same error!can you please help me to understand it better what I am doing wrong

Comment: I think you need to edit the question and add the code you use to setup pymongo and create the collections.